# rss-parser: Uncaught TypeError: get is not a function at Parser.js:79:1

Tags: javascript, webpack, rss

I'm making an RSS parser with the Node package [rss-parser](https://github.com/rbren/rss-parser) but I think it's only currently compatible with Webpack 4 because webpack 4 auto-shims Node built-ins, but I'm a `newb.js` so I need help. You can read about [Shimming in Webpack here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/) and [Upgrading Webpack from 4 to 5 here](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/). Here is the line that is blowing up (parser:79)

```
let req = get(requestOpts, (res) => {
```

Here is the entire function.

```
  parseURL(feedUrl, callback, redirectCount=0) {
    let xml = '';
    let get = feedUrl.indexOf('https') === 0 ? https.get : http.get;
    let urlParts = url.parse(feedUrl);
    let headers = Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_HEADERS, this.options.headers);
    let timeout = null;
    let prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const requestOpts = Object.assign({headers}, urlParts, this.options.requestOptions);
      let req = get(requestOpts, (res) => {
        if (this.options.maxRedirects && res.statusCode >= 300 && res.statusCode < 400 && res.headers['location']) {
          if (redirectCount === this.options.maxRedirects) {
            return reject(new Error("Too many redirects"));
          } else {
            const newLocation = url.resolve(feedUrl, res.headers['location']);
            return this.parseURL(newLocation, null, redirectCount + 1).then(resolve, reject);
          }
        } else if (res.statusCode >= 300) {
          return reject(new Error("Status code " + res.statusCode))
        }
        let encoding = utils.getEncodingFromContentType(res.headers['content-type']);
        res.setEncoding(encoding);
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          xml += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
          return this.parseString(xml).then(resolve, reject);
        });
      })
      req.on('error', reject);
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        return reject(new Error("Request timed out after " + this.options.timeout + "ms"));
      }, this.options.timeout);
    }).then(data => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      return Promise.resolve(data);
    }, e => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      return Promise.reject(e);
    });
    prom = utils.maybePromisify(callback, prom);
    return prom;
  }
```

Here is the stack trace from Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: get is not a function
    at Parser.js:79:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Parser.parseURL (Parser.js:76:1)
    at FeedRSSPrint (Popup.tsx:18:1)
    at App (Popup.tsx:30:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26560:1)
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.195",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "entities": "^4.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23"
  }
```

I also had to add this to the webpack configuration:

```
module.resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    fallback: { "http": false, "browser": false, "https": false, 
      "stream": false, "url": false, "buffer": false, "timers": false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not loading rss-parser from the pre-built 'rss-parser.min.js' file. When I tried to compile the rss-parser, I needed to do some stuff for Node.JS with fallback, but you don't need to do that when you use the `rss-parser.min.js` file. I'm using TypeScript so I just added this to my parser file and it works just fine.

```
interface Enclosure {
  url: string
  length: number
  type: string
}

interface Item {
  link: string
  guid: string
  title: string
  pubDate: string
  creator: string
  summary: string
  content: string
  isoDate: string
  categories?: string[]
  contentSnippet: string 
  enclosure: Enclosure
}
```